# Carregar objetos de outras classes

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, primefaces, hibernate

Tenho um `selectOneMenu` que servirá para listar todas as Gerações (dados no banco). Estes dados devem ser listados na hora de cadastrar um objeto Nature. O meu `selectOneMenu` está assim :

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{msg['geracao']}" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="geracao" value="#{msg['geracao']}">
<f:selectItem value="" />
<f:selectItems value="#{naturemb.geracoes}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:message for="geracao" />
```

O Controller de Nature está assim:

```
package br.com.pokemax.controle;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import br.com.pokemax.modelo.Geracao;
import br.com.pokemax.modelo.Nature;
import br.com.pokemax.negocio.NatureDAO;
import br.com.pokemax.util.MensagensUtil;

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "naturemb")
public class ControleNature implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Nature nature;

    @Inject
    private NatureDAO dao;

    private List<Nature> lista;

    private List<Geracao> geracoes;

    @PostConstruct
    public void inicio() {

    }

    public void novo() {
        nature = new Nature();
    }

    public void gravar() {
        try {
            if (nature.getId() == null) {
                dao.insert(nature);
                MensagensUtil.msg("Info", "cadastro.sucesso", new Object[] { MensagensUtil.get("nature") });
                nature = new Nature();
            } else {
                dao.update(nature);
                MensagensUtil.msg("Info", "alterado.sucesso", new Object[] { MensagensUtil.get("nature") });
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
            return;
        }

    }

    public void pesquisar() {
        try {
            lista = dao.findAll();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void excluir(Nature h) {
        try {
            dao.delete(h);
            MensagensUtil.msg("Info", "removido.sucesso", new Object[] { MensagensUtil.get("nature") });
            pesquisar();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public void editar(Long id) {
        try {
            setNature(dao.find(id));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

    }

    public void cancelar() {
        nature = null;

    }

    public Nature getNature() {
        return nature;
    }

    public List<Geracao> getGeracoes() {
        return geracoes;
    }

    public void setGeracoes(List<Geracao> geracoes) {
        this.geracoes = geracoes;
    }

    public void setNature(Nature nature) {
        this.nature = nature;
    }

    public List<Nature> getLista() {
        return lista;
    }

    public void setLista(List<Nature> lista) {
        this.lista = lista;
    }

}
```

Como eu faço pra carregar todas as Gerações no meu `selectOneMenu` ?

Comment: Já deu uma olhada no exemplo na documentação? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml Pode detalhar qual parte do exemplo você não compreendeu? E, cara, tira esses *try-catch* daí, por favor!! hehehe

Comment: rsrsrs....Quais try/catch ?

Comment: @Caffé eu até tinha olhado este exemplo...mas não entendi bem a parte pra puxar do banco, etc, criei um Converter já.

Comment: Sua dúvida é como puxar do banco ou como exibir na tela? O código da página parece correto. No Java, você tem que fazer algo como `return geracoesDao.findAll()` no `getGeracoes`.

Comment: @Caffé certo....mas neste caso não se usa o converter ?

Answer (score 0):

Analisando rapidamente seu código, percebi que o método pesquisar não foi processado, está apenas implementado. Invoque-o dentro do método inicio, pois vi que tem um @PostConstruct ou então na sua tela insira uma tag f:metadata e o chame, tipo assim:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/LayoutPadrao.xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" 
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" 
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{seuBean.pesquisar}" type="preRenderView" />
</f:metadata>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sobre o converter é necessário devido em páginas JSF os dados serem Strings, e quando você retorna uma lista os dados são objetos e precisam ser convertidos em Strings e resumidamente este é o papel do converter, abaixo está um exemplo da implementação de um converter e também de chamada dele na view:

//Converter

```
@Named("fabricanteConverter")
public class FabricanteConverter implements Converter {

@Inject
FabricanteService fabricanteService;

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    System.out.println("Valor = " + value);
    return (value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) ? fabricanteService.listarPorId(Long.parseLong(value)) : null;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object obj) {
    return obj != null ? String.valueOf(((Fabricante) obj).getId()) : null;
}
```

}

//Chamando o converter na view

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="tipodocumento" value="#{cadastroDocumentoBean.documentoConceito.tipoDocumento}" >
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" noSelectionOption="true" />
<f:selectItems value="#{cadastroDocumentoBean.tiposDocumento}" var="tipoDocumento" itemValue="#{tipoDocumento}" itemLabel="#{tipoDocumento.descricao}"/>
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Onde ele é chamado ?